# Add SQL to function called 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, function

I have a button called "Add" which relates to each person in a list.

```
  echo <td><input type=\"submit\" id=\"PlayerAdded".$id."\" value=\"Add\" 
  onclick=\"add('".$id."','".$name."','".$_SESSION['GameID']."');\"></input></td>";
```

When "Add" is clicked, I want to add the persons details to a table (working fine), and also add a new row including their name and ID into a table in my DB (this is my problem).

I am aware that PHP won't work in a JS function. I'm also aware that I should never access the database on my site from JS due to the security issues.

**So how can I have a button which `onclick` calls a function which adds to the database?**

I tried writing my function in PHP, but it wasn't doing anything when I clicked the button. See my function below:

```
function add(id,name,game){
    var t = ("</td><td>");
    var str = ("<tr id='Players" + id + "'><td>")
    var ctr = ("</td></tr>")

    var PID = ("<input type = 'hidden' name='ID" + id + "' value='" + id + "'></input>" + id)
    var Pnam = ("<input type='hidden' name='Name" + id + "' value='" +  name + "'></input>");
    var place = ("<select name='Place" + id + "'><option value='17'>17th</option><option value='16'>16th</option><option value='15'>15th</option><option value='14'>14th</option><option value='13'>13th</option><option value='12'>12th</option><option value='11'>11th</option><option value='10'>10th</option><option value='9'>9th</option><option value='8'>8th</option><option value='7'>7th</option><option value='6'>6th</option><option value='5'>5th</option><option value='4'>4th</option><option value='3'>3rd</option><option value='2'>2nd</option><option value='1'>1st</option></select>")
    var points = ("<form action='leaderboards.php' method='post' target='_blank'><input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='" + id + "'></input><input type='hidden' name='name' value='" + name + "'></input><input type='submit' value='View'></form>");
    var cash = ("$<input name='Cash" + id + "' placeholder=' 0'></input>");
    var ticket = ("<select name='Ticket" + id + "'><option value='No'>No</option><option value='Yes'>Yes</option>");
    var del = ("<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='remove(" + id + ")'> </input>")

   $('#PlayerAdded').before(str+ PID + t + Pnam + name + t + place + t + points + t + cash + t + ticket + t + del + ctr);

// This is where I want to insert into the db. Similar to 
      // <?php
      // $sql = "INSERT INTO results (`col`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$game')"; 
      // mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql); ?>
//but I want to be able to do it inside this java script function.

  }
```

Comment: you need to make an `ajax` call

Comment: Thank you. I've not yet learnt ajax. Where can I insert the call?
Would the AJAX run the SQL similarly to how it works in php?

Comment: if you can explain your question clearly with screenshots I can help you

Comment: just write a php with the comments you have posted and then make an ajax call by passing the values to it. $.ajax in jquery

Comment: that function which you have already written is it getting called ?

Comment: thanks for that. The function `add()` is getting called by the `onclick` from the section above.

Just to clarify I am understanding your answer above, are you suggesting that I should write that php code as a separate function, and then inside the `add()` function I should use ajax to call the php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the bracket before the variables, which you have written for every variable in function.

Add the `ajax` piece at the end of your function code.

```
function add(id, name, game) {
    var t = "</td><td>";
    var str = "<tr id='Players" + id + "'><td>"
    var ctr = "</td></tr>"

    var PID = "<input type = 'hidden' name='ID" + id + "' value='" + id + "'></input>" + id;
    var Pnam = "<input type='hidden' name='Name" + id + "' value='" + name + "'></input>";
    var place = "<select name='Place" + id + "'><option value='17'>17th</option><option value='16'>16th</option><option value='15'>15th</option><option value='14'>14th</option><option value='13'>13th</option><option value='12'>12th</option><option value='11'>11th</option><option value='10'>10th</option><option value='9'>9th</option><option value='8'>8th</option><option value='7'>7th</option><option value='6'>6th</option><option value='5'>5th</option><option value='4'>4th</option><option value='3'>3rd</option><option value='2'>2nd</option><option value='1'>1st</option></select>";
    var points = "<form action='leaderboards.php' method='post' target='_blank'><input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='" + id + "'></input><input type='hidden' name='name' value='" + name + "'></input><input type='submit' value='View'></form>";
    var cash = "$<input name='Cash" + id + "' placeholder=' 0'></input>";
    var ticket = "<select name='Ticket" + id + "'><option value='No'>No</option><option value='Yes'>Yes</option>";
    var del = "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='remove(" + id + ")'> </input>";

    $('#PlayerAdded').before(str + PID + t + Pnam + name + t + place + t + points + t + cash + t + ticket + t + del + ctr);

    // making ajax call to insert.php and posting the data
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
            "game": game
        },
         beforeSend:function(){
            // show something before data is saved to db.
         }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        $("body").append(msg); //debugging purpose
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['game'])){
      $id= $_POST['id'];
      $name= $_POST['name'];
      $game= $_POST['game'];   

    //write your connection logic

    // never write bare queries there is a chance of sql injection.
    //Instead use prepared statement, prepare your query then bind the above values to it, then excute. 
    //write your insert logic below.
}
?>
```

Comment: that query better be done with prepared statement, i know in his original code he doesn't use it but it could be very dangerous to avoid it +1

Comment: that is just example purpose. i am not adding my inputs on php because his question is on ajax, i know about `sql injection`

Comment: so if I 
1) Copy the code from the first example to the end of my function, then 
2) create a new file called **insert.php** and include a file called (for example) `connecttodb.php`, then replace the code between the first and 3rd comments with `include("connecttodb.php");` then it should work?

Comment: hmmm.... I have applied your answer and I am getting the alert, the data is outputting to the table and I get no error messages, but the data is still not going to the database. I even tested with a deliberate error (swapped $conn for $con in the mysqli_query) and still got no error. I don't know if the ajax is activating `insert.php`.

Comment: if alert is coming then there is issue in your php, check nicely for single quotes double quotes, check in `network tab` `f12`

Comment: remove those brackets your wrapped around all the variables in javascript. past your php code which you tried in `insert.php`

Comment: I really don't see where the error is, but the lines `    }).done(function(msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    });` are returning a very long error message

Comment: that is your php error may be. post your `insert.php` please

Comment: `<?php
   if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['game'])){
    $id= $_POST['id'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $game= $_POST['game'];   

include ('dbconnect.php');

    // never write bare queries there is a chance of sql injection.Instead use prepared statement, prepare your query then bind the above values to it, then excute. below is just what you have posted in question.

     $sql = "INSERT INTO results (`PlayerID`,`Name`,`GameID`) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$game')"; 
    mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql); 

}
?>`

Comment: where is your `$dbcon` variable defined? I see that you just include dbconnect.php

Comment: $dbcon is defined in dbconnect.php

Comment: instead of `alert("Data Saved: " + msg);` replace  with       `$(body).append(msg);`. and see what error is printed

Comment: sorry `$("body").append(msg);` body in double quotes

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\UPT Site\insert.php on line 4 ------ Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\UPT Site\insert.php on line 5 ----------Notice: Undefined index: game in C:\wamp\www\UPT Site\insert.php on line 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93224/discussion-between-tunna182-and-susheel-singh).

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the values you want to insert to your database via `AJAX`, append this to your `add()` function:

```
$.post('insertnew.php', { id:id,name:name,game:game }, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

**insertnew.php:**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['game'])){
    // sanitize your data here, then:
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $game = $_POST['game'];

   //connect to your db, or instead include your dbconnect.php
      $link= new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

   // check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
         exit();
     }
   //use prepared statement, prepare your query then bind the above values to it, then excute
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO results VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $id, $name, $game);

     if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
          echo "Record has been added successfully";
     }else{
          echo "Sorry, record could not be inserted";
     }
   }
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php